# Is there any way to edit both image and input field simultaneously using one handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I am trying to edit image using react-native-image-picker and input field using forkik. But I have one handler and when I pic image to update, text field remains undefined. When I select both and upload them simultaneously it gives me success but I am using separate edit button, also want single handler for both of them.

```
handleSubmit(values) {
      if (values){
        let obj = {};   
        obj["id"] =  this.props.reducer_data[0].user.id;
        obj["first_name"] = values.name;
        obj["last_name"] = this.props.reducer_data[0].user.last_name;   
        this.EditUserApiCall(this.state.photo , obj);
      } 
    }
```

and API call

```
async EditUserApiCall(photo , otherParams) {
      const url = 'https://example.com/sub/cat';
      try {
          const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: this.createFormData(photo, otherParams),
          });
          const json = await response.json();
          this.props.userDetail(json);
      } 
      catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          alert("Upload failed!");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use a simple if else statement to check which one is being updated and update the respective fields and reassign their same values for the rest of the fields.. This way you can update the required field in a single handler without getting the other fields as undefined

Comment: May you please explain me in code? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Where i should place if else condition?

Comment: Inside EditUserApiCall function

Comment: If you can explain with psudo code i will be very thankful to you